# Como decompilar un archivo .exe

Tags: java, c++

Tengo un archivo "programa" .exe que al abrirlo se abre la interfaz como si fuera CMD, no se en qué lenguaje esta escrito, y quisiera saber cómo decompilarlo para mirar el código fuente.

Comment: Quizá quisiste decir decompilarlo, existen diversas herramientas, pero estas te mostrarán el código en lenguaje ensamblador, lo que es más difícil de entender, si sabes en qué lenguaje fue hecho el programa, es más fácil siempre y cuando el código no esté ofuscado, pues será un dolor de cabeza entenderlo. Estas son las que mas conozco: 1-Codigo C# y visual Basic = Reflector.net: Permite exportar el codigo a una solucion de visual estudio. 2-Código Java= Java Decompiler Te recomiendo investigar un poco sobre Ingeniería Inversa para que entres mas en el tema.